# Várias linhas em um coluna Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com um problema onde preciso juntar o retorno de uma consulta feita em duas tabelas em uma única linha.

Pensei em usar `PIVOT` mas não consegui por causa do `INNER JOIN`.

A consulta está assim:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english; 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, ftd.DateAndTime, 113) dt, 
round(ftd.Val, 2) Val, ttd.TagName 
FROM FloatTableDiario ftd INNER JOIN TagTableDiario ttd 
ON ttd.TagIndex = ftd.TagIndex 
WHERE ftd.Marker = 'S' 
AND ftd.DateAndTime BETWEEN '05-29-2018 00:00:000' AND '05-29-2018 23:59:059' 
AND ttd.TagName 
IN('[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_NR', 
 '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_DA', 
 '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdHou', 
 '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdMin', 
 '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdHou_DA ', 
 '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdMin_DA', 
 '[AGUA]LT_MAX_DA[0]', 
 '[AGUA]LT_MIN_DA[0]') 
ORDER BY ftd.DateAndTime
```

O retorno obviamente vem em uma linha diferente para cara valor do `IN`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que todo o resultado venha em uma única linha, a cada intervalo será gerado mais de 400 dados.

Comment: Adiciona um group by pela data 

 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, ftd.DateAndTime, 113) dt, round(ftd.Val, 2) Val, ttd.TagName FROM FloatTableDiario ftd INNER JOIN TagTableDiario ttd ON ttd.TagIndex = ftd.TagIndex WHERE ftd.Marker = 'S' AND ftd.DateAndTime BETWEEN '05-29-2018 00:00:000' AND '05-29-2018 23:59:059' AND ttd.TagName IN('[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_NR', '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_DA', '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdHou', '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdMin', '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdHou_DA ', '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdMin_DA', '[AGUA]LT_MAX_DA[0]', '[AGUA]LT_MIN_DA[0]') group by dt ORDER BY ftd.DateAndTime

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, infelizmente não resolveu.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse exemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/17073196/9916784 e veja se resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode sempre tentar com um `FOR XML`:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english

SELECT      (
                SELECT      CONVERT(VARCHAR, ftd.DateAndTime, 113)  + ';'
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROUND(ftd.Val, 2))     + ';'
                            ttd.TagName
                FROM        FloatTableDiario    ftd 
                INNER JOIN  TagTableDiario      ttd ON ttd.TagIndex = ftd.TagIndex 
                WHERE       ftd.Marker = 'S' 
                        AND ftd.DateAndTime BETWEEN '05-29-2018 00:00:000' AND '05-29-2018 23:59:059' 
                        AND ttd.TagName IN  (       '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_NR'
                                                ,   '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_DA'
                                                ,   '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdHou'
                                                ,   '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdMin'
                                                ,   '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdHou_DA'
                                                ,   '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdMin_DA'
                                                ,   '[AGUA]LT_MAX_DA[0]'
                                                ,   '[AGUA]LT_MIN_DA[0]'
                                            )
                ORDER BY    ftd.DateAndTime
                FOR XML PATH('')
            )
```

Utilizei o separador ";" mas poderá construir o texto da forma que entender.